# Cant use parseInt() in LocalHost NodeJS - Body Parser

Tags: node.js, express

im actully new in node js so i got this error while using **parseInt or Number()** in my server

code :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/bmicalculator", function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/bmicalculator", function(req, res) {
    var nm1 = parseInt(req.body.num1); // <-- here the error
    var nm2 = parseInt(req.body.num2); // <-- here the error
    var result = nm1 + nm2 * nm2;
    res.send(result);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server started");
});
```

**here the error from Browser & Terminal :**

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 29636
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:248:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:239:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:763:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)   
    at C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\calculator.js:16:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)     
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\Calculator\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
```

Comment: are you sure it fails because parseInt? because the error indicates `ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE` and according to the [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) `parseInt` does not throw an exception, but will return `NaN` if the parse cannot happen

Comment: which row throws the exception?

Comment: @Omri Attiya i dont know, but when i remove that parseInt 
it working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be caused by the method `res.send`. In old version of Express (v3), 
the first argument used to be http status code but in your case, it's a big number (invalid http status code), hence the error is thrown.

in order to fix this, you can do either

- upgrade to a newer version of express.
- do this `res.send(200, result)` instead.

See the Express v3 docs here for reference: https://expressjs.com/en/3x/api.html#res.send

```
res.send([body|status], [body])
Send a response.

res.send(Buffer.from('whoop'))
res.send({ some: 'json' })
res.send('<p>some html</p>')
res.send(404, 'Sorry, we cannot find that!')
res.send(500, { error: 'something blew up' })
res.send(200)
```

You can see your case is same as the last example but your first argument is a big number 29636, which is invalid status code.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

And change the reponse to:

```
res.send(200, result);
```